Scrapy splash cannot perform js like what I did directly in the browser terminal
I am recently try using scrapy splash to scrape data from a website that loads more data when scrolls to bottom. website: https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/restaurants/district/%E5%B0%96%E6%B2%99%E5%92%80
so I first try to perform scrolling in console of dev tools using JavaScript:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, (document.body.scrollHeight-1500)), i * 2000);
}

(I set the y-coord to (document.body.scrollHeight-1500) because it cannot load when it is at the very end, so it needs to be a bit upper)
The js code works perfectly when do this in the dev tool on browser, so i put this in scrapy splash:
and here's my code:
import scrapy
from Task2.items import RestaurantItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
  splash:go(args.url)
  splash:wait(5.0)
  local scroll = splash:jsfunc([[
    function scrollWithDelay() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, (document.body.scrollHeight-1500)), i * 2000);
        }
    }
  ]])
  scroll()
  splash:wait(5.0)
  return {html = splash:html()}
end
"""

class OpenriceTstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "openrice_tst"
    allowed_domains = ["www.openrice.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/restaurants/district/%E5%B0%96%E6%B2%99%E5%92%80"
        yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='execute', 
                            args={'wait': 2, 'lua_source': lua_script, 'viewport': '1920x1080',
                                  url: "https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/restaurants/district/%E5%B0%96%E6%B2%99%E5%92%80"})

    def parse(self, response):
        ...

I am only getting the first 20 search result from the website, which could be loaded when i keep scrolling down, it was there before using any js.
So i want to know if I missed any detail or i write anything wrong on my code? I can get some result but it is not from the js, the js works perfectly on my browser, so the problem is either the scrapy-splash is not working, or my lua script is wrong, i keep searching for 2 days and still cannot find a solution, i will give you a big thanks if u can help me!
Also is it possible that I can force it to show all result without scrolling? Thank you so much for everyone that would like to help me...

I also couldn't get this to work with Splash.
However, there is an API behind the site and you can just extract the data directly from that.
This will grab the first page of 15 results.
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
}

params = {
    'uiLang': 'zh',
    'uiCity': 'hongkong',
    'districtId': '2008',
    'regionId': '0',
    'startAt': '0',
    'rows': '15',
    'pageToken': 'CONST_DUMMY_TOKEN',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.openrice.com/api/v2/search', params=params, headers=headers)

data = response.json()

for result in data["paginationResult"]["results"]:
    print(result["name"])

Here's what the data look like:
Gram cafe & pancakes
Lady Nara
Mamaday
Outdark (H8)
Nara Thai Cuisine (港威商場)
十和田總本店
JUST'er Bar & Restaurant
Amitie Kitchen
The Grill Room (The Humphreys)
Café Crêpe (K11購物藝術館)
牛魔
hoo韓國包車
古今二 (The ONE)
小魚兒 (金馬大廈)
鬼金棒

The JSON returned by the API has got a lot more data than just the name. You can dump the response to a text file and dig around in the JSON to find what you are looking for.
To implement pagination via the API you'd just need to loop over the requests, incrementing the value in the 'startAt' parameter by 15 each time. Stop when there are no new results.

OMG thank you so much! Since the biggest problem i have is to find all url to different restarant, i can now access to the url using
data = response.json() data["paginationResult"]["results"]["shortenUrl"]
with the url i think i can scrape the data using my scrapy code again! this really helps me a lot tysm! also i got a small question, how do u find this api?

I am new to api, so may i know how u can find those parameter to pass into the api?

Good question! It looks like you don't need the districtId parameter. The other parameters (uiLang and uiCity) match the values in the URL provided in the original question.
